# Conversion Error in SQL Server - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, syntax-error

I have code shown below that I can not find what is causing the conversion error. Can someone help identify the issue?

```
[COLUMN_A] = CASE
                WHEN [COLUMN_B] IS NOT NULL 
                     AND [COLUMN_B] <> '' 
                     AND CHARINDEX('MG', [COLUMN_B], 1)  <> 0  
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 4), RTRIM(LEFT([COLUMN_B], CHARINDEX('MG', [COLUMN_B], 1))) 
                WHEN [COLUMN_B] IS NOT NULL 
                     AND [COLUMN_B] <> '' 
                     AND CHARINDEX('MCG', [COLUMN_B], 1) <> 0  
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 4), RTRIM(LEFT([COLUMN_B], CHARINDEX('MCG', [COLUMN_B], -1)))
                WHEN [COLUMN_B] IS NOT NULL 
                     AND [COLUMN_B] <> '' 
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 4), RTRIM([COLUMN_B]))
                ELSE NULL  
    END
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please provide sample data. I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that you're making some assumptions about what the strings look like and where you can actually cut the string to yield a decimal.

Comment: @Xedni - there *is* no possible data that can match the first two branches of the case expression and be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

For the case that `COLUMN_B` contains the string `'MCG'` you are using the expression

```
LEFT([COLUMN_B], CHARINDEX('MCG', [COLUMN_B], -1))
```

Let's look at what that returns for strings containing this substring

```
+-----------+---------+
| COLUMN_B  | Returns |
+-----------+---------+
| MCG       | M       |
| MCG 12.45 | M       |
| 12.45 MCG | 12.45 M |
+-----------+---------+
```

So you can see that any string containing `MCG` is guaranteed to produce a non numeric result as they all contain the first letter of the matched substring. So this is bound to fail to cast to decimal.

It makes no sense to pass `-1` as the third argument to `CHARINDEX`. This is the `start_location` and a string doesn't have negative characters.

I assume you are trying to find the charindex and then subtract one to extract everything to the left of the substring without including the `M`.

So you need

```
LEFT([COLUMN_B], CHARINDEX('MCG', [COLUMN_B]) -1)
```

For a `COLUMN_B` value of `12.45 MCG` this will return 12.45 `and then your`RTRIM` will remove the trailing space.

The same also applies to your other `CHARINDEX` expression.

Also you can remove the first two instances of `[COLUMN_B] IS NOT NULL AND [COLUMN_B] <> ''` - because if it matches the `charindex` test it will be not null and not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
[COLUMN_A] = CASE
            WHEN try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]) IS NOT NULL 
                 AND try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]) <> '' 
                 AND CHARINDEX('MG', try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]), 1)  <> 0  
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 4), RTRIM(LEFT(try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]), CHARINDEX('MG', try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]), 1))) 
            WHEN try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]) IS NOT NULL 
                 AND try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]) <> '' 
                 AND CHARINDEX('MCG', try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]), 1) <> 0  
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 4), RTRIM(LEFT(try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]), CHARINDEX('MCG', try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]), -1)))
            WHEN try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]) IS NOT NULL 
                 AND try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B]) <> '' 
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 4), RTRIM(try_convert(nvarchar(max),[COLUMN_B])))
            ELSE NULL  
END
```

This should get you at least past the error and allow you to at least get it to run through the use of the inline try catch function.